# Resumen de datos con DataTables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables, count

Hola cordial saludo tengo un inconveniente al hacer una actividad.

- lo que quisiera hacer es un resumen de datos en una nueva tabla que según el responsable me muestre el conteo de actividades:
  muestro una imagen de como quiero mostrarlo:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

obteniendo de los datos que tengo en mi tabla principal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
para mi tabla principal uso DataTables

Este es mi script para implementar datatable

```js
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var tableadmin = $('#admin').DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSider: true,
      ordering: false,
      "pageLength": 10,
      "lengthMenu": [[5,10,50,-1], [5,10,50,"All"]],
      "autoWidth": false,
      "language":{
        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/i18n/Spanish.json"
      }
    });
    //FILTROS
    $('.filter-input').keyup(function(){
      tableadmin.column($(this).data('column'))
      .search($(this).val())
      .draw();
    });
    $('.filter-select').change(function(){
      tableadmin.column($(this).data('column'))
    .search($(this).val())
    .draw();
    });
    $('input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
    var offices = $('input:checkbox[name="adm"]:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get().join('|');
    tableadmin.column(7).search(offices, true, false, false).draw();
    });
    //FIN FILTROS
  });
</script>
```

Me podrían decir o guiarme de como poder implementar ese nuevo cuadro, agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Hola JL, de donde obtienes los datos y como los manejas? conJSON o con una api?

Comment: Uso laravel y mediante un controlador obtengo los datos.

Comment: Ok, de cualquier forma tienes que crear un controlador que te obtenga esa informacion. pienso que seria un poco mas complejo.

Comment: ok muchas gracias